# Eclipse Android import into Android Studio - no destination directory offered

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-studio

I am trying to move some Android 6 Cordova 5.1 applications from Eclipse 2018-09 to Android Studio (AS) V3.2.
Following AS instructions, I check that the project folder root has an *AndroidManifest.xml* file and  *res/* and *src*/ directories. In AS I select Import project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.) and select 'your the Eclipse project folder,...'. All well so far.

However, I am not offered an *Import Destination Directory* option and AS goes on to use the Eclipse source instead.  DAK why?

Answer (score 0):

The short version is that Eclipse and Android Studio use different folder structures.

I had to make the base Activity and copy all files into the new folder structure then one by one and reconnect them.